# Is $A_1^i \overline{A_1^j} A_1^k \overline{A_1^{\ell}} = \overline{A_i^1} A_j^1 A_1^k \overline{A_1^{\ell}} = \delta_i^k \delta_j^{\ell}$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices

Let $A = (A_i^j)$ be a unitary matrix. That is, $A^{-1} = \overline{A}^t$.

Is it true that $$A_1^i \overline{A_1^j} A_1^k \overline{A_1^{\ell}} = \overline{A_i^1} A_j^1 A_1^k \overline{A_1^{\ell}} = \delta_i^k \delta_j^{\ell}?$$

Comment: That would imply $A_{1}^{i} A_{1}^{k}$ is proportional to $\delta_i^k$, ie. equal to $\delta_i^k$ times a scalar  (by "factoring" the relationship according to groups of indices that appear both on the left and right side). However, $\delta_i^k$ is a rank $n$ matrix, while   $A_{1}^{i} A_{1}^{k}$ is a rank $1$ matrix (note the constant index $1$) .

Comment: @user3257842 Ah, of course, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the more general case of orthogonal matrices the equation already doesn't hold. Suppose $A$ to be the rotation matrix by an angle $\theta\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ which is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos{\theta}&-\sin{\theta}\\
\sin{\theta}& \quad\cos{\theta}
\end{pmatrix}$$
This matrix is orthogonal and for $i,k=1$ and $j,\ell=2$ we get
$$A_1^i\overline{A_1^j}A_1^k\overline{A_1^{\ell}}=\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)\neq 0$$
and
$$\overline{A_i^1}A_j^1A_1^k\overline{A_1^{\ell}}=-\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)\neq 0.$$
Therefore both terms are not equal. In the case of $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$ neither of terms equals 1 meaning they both can't be of the form $\delta_j^k\delta_j^{\ell}$, assuming you mean the dirac delta.

Comment: I appreciate this, thank you!